# Is it possible to make $R = \{(1, 0), (0, 1) \}$ antisymmetric without removing elements?

Tags: relations

I was wondering if I have the relation $R = \{(1, 0), (0, 1) \}$, is there any way I can make the relation antisymmetric **without** removing elements? I think not, because since the first part of the anti-symmetric implication is true, there is no way the second part $a = b$ will ever be true as long as the initial two elements are part of the relation.

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: It is possible if you put an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\{0,1\}$ such that $0 \sim 1$ and consider $R$ with respect to $\sim$... then $R$ becomes the same as $\{(*,*)\}$ on $\{*\}^2$, though, so it's pretty useless...

Comment: Thank you, just wanted to make sure, if I understood it correctly